# When to use "He is dead" and when to use "He was dead"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

In the [dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/dead):

> **Dead**: no longer alive
>
> Her mother had been dead for ten years.
>
> Her parents were long dead.
>
> The man was already dead

So, what is the difference between "**He is dead**" & "**He was dead**"?

If we choose other adjective "**nice**" for example, then it is so easy

**He is nice**: At this moment he is nice

**He was nice**: He was nice in the past but we don't know if he is nice now

But: **He is dead**: At this moment he is no longer alive, but when he is dead, that event was already in the past even if it only happens a few seconds ago

Or we can say "**He has just been dead**" seems accurate

**He was dead**: He is no longer alive in the past.

When to use "**He is dead**" and when to use "**He was dead**"?

Answer (score 3):

English *narrative* normally uses the past tense, even to describe ongoing action:

> The policeman **walked** over to the man lying in the dark alley.  There **was** little doubt that he **was** dead.

Otherwise, in everyday conversation or dialogue, use the present tense.

> "My parents **are** both dead," she said with a shrug.  "I guess that **makes** me an orphan."

Comment: "He was dead" means he was dead then; "he is dead" is a statement about the present. Regarding the rest of the question, "He has just been dead" is not natural: "he has/had just died" is idiomatic.